# Selecting the distinct values from three columns with the max of a fourth where there are duplicates

Tags: sql, oracle, distinct, max

I have a table with one numeric value (n) and three string values (a,b,c). How do I query this table so that I get only distinct values of (a,b,c) and if there are duplicates, take the maximum of the corresponding set of n values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select max(n), a, b, c
from mytable
group by a, b, c
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `GROUP BY`:

```
select a, b, c, max(n) 
from table 
group by a, b, c;
```

This will show only unique or distinct sets of `a, b, c` and show the maximum `n` found in that set.

`MAX` is an aggregate function designed for use with `GROUP BY`.  Other potentially useful aggregate functions include `MIN`, `AVERAGE`, and `COUNT`.