# Distinct on each column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, distinct

I need to select `3` columns from a table, but I need each value from any column to be unique in the resultset for this column.

This query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 10 a, b, c
FROM   x
```

will return `10` distinct sets.

How do I do it?

Comment: It's difficult to understand what you mean. Perhaps an example of your data and an example of the expected output might help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
WITH q AS
        (
        SELECT  a, b, с, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY a, b, c) AS rn
        FROM    mytable
        )
SELECT  TOP 10 a, b, c
FROM    q q1
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  1
        FROM    q
        WHERE   q.rn < q1.rn
                AND q.a = q1.a
        )
        AND NOT EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  1
        FROM    q
        WHERE   q.rn < q1.rn
                AND q.b = q1.b
        )
        AND NOT EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  1
        FROM    q
        WHERE   q.rn < q1.rn
                AND q.c = q1.c
        )
```

Comment: That's some beautiful tsql +1

Comment: @ichiban: thanks :) I'm gonna make today's post in my blog out of it

Comment: Mighty roundabout way of saying Select a,b,c From x Group By a,b,c or what did I miss?

Comment: @Amit: your query may return `1, 2, 3` and `1, 2, 4` which makes `a` and `b` not unique in the resultset.

Comment: @Quassnoi: Ah, I didn't catch that requirement from the question. As spender said, its hard to understand this one without examples. I interpreted "distinct sets" differently, such that 123 and 124 are distinct.

Comment: @Amit: the title says "distinct on each column", what's so hard about it? The op emphasized that distinct sets is not what she wants.

Comment: @quassnoi: Yes, and `1,2,3` is distinct on each column. So is `1,2,4`. But now that I re-read for the third time, I _finally_ see how by "this query returns distinct sets" OP was not referring to the desired solution query. This is what I meant I missed.

Answer (score 1):

does [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/467329/selecting-the-distinct-values-from-three-columns-with-the-max-of-a-fourth-where-t) not give you what you want?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is possible in one shot. I would do this by creating a table variable.

```
DECLARE @Results TABLE
(
  a varchar(100),
  b varchar(100),
  c varchar(100)
)
INSERT @Results(a)
SELECT DISTINCT a FROM myTable

INSERT @Results(b)
SELECT DISTINCT b FROM myTable

INSERT @Results(c)
SELECT DISTINCT c FROM myTable

SELECT a,b,c FROM @Results
```